# AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'MyContext' only declares a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In the following console application (.Net core 2.0), the `scaffold-dbcontext` created the following `DbContext`

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Tables> Tables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) { optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Program.Conn); }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { .... }
}
```

In the Main() (`static void Main(string[] args)`), the following code

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
var conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("MySource");
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(conn)); // Error
```

got the following run-time error?

> AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'MyContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to AddDbContext will never be used

Answer (score 137, accepted):

As the error said it if you configure your `MyContext` through `AddDbContext` then you need too add a constructor that receive a parameter of type `DbContextOptions<MyContext>` into your `MyContext` class like below

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }
```

If you don't do that, ASP.Net Core will not be able to inject the configuration you set with `AddDbContext`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the default scaffolded code shouldn't be changed. However, now I have another issue - I cannot get the connection string, I posted a question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948141/configuration-getconnectionstringmyconn-got-null-value.

Comment: Right now I cannot do the final test because of the null connection string, let me try to hard code the connection string for testing.... Yes, the change works. Thank you.

Comment: Note: this is a partial class so you should add the constructor to a second file if you're autogenerating your context

Comment: This is the same constructor to add for the new `services.AddDbContextPool()`  method added to `EF Core 2.0`

Comment: This addition got my code a little farther along. thank you

Comment: I guess this is a lesson in using the templates - I started with an empty project and was wondering why Configuration was not showing up. This did it. Thanks!

Comment: I have "options.UseSqlServer" in two files and I got this error. Actually trying to connect to the database twice. One for MyProjectDBContext and IdentityDBContext. I mixed them into one.