# configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConn") got null value?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In the following console application (.Net core 2.0), the `conn` got a null value.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: false).Build();

services.AddSingleton(configuration);

var conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConn"); // conn is null
```

The following is App.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConn" connectionString="....." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <Settings>
    <Name>Test</Name>
  </Settings>
</configuration>
```

There is some code which can get the value ("Test") of `Name` of the `Settings` successfully.

**Update:**

Right after the assignment of `conn`, I have the following code to get `<Settings>` section of the XML part and it can get the value "Test".

```
var myOptions = new MyOptions();
configuration.GetSection("Settings").Bind(myOptions);
```

Comment: So there is some parts of your app which can retrieve the connection string, and some which cannot? Care to elaborate?

Comment: I have other code to get `configuration.GetSection("Setting")...`, not the `connectionString` part.

Comment: Even though this is .NET Core, wouldn't there not be an `app.config`? Wouldn't it still be named `myassembly.exe.config`?

Comment: @TyCobb, I have another code to get the `<Settings>...` part of the value and it works.

Comment: if you do  `optional: false` does it throws an exception? If true then make sure you give the correct path of the file.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, just updated the question, the xml path should be ok. I changed the `option:` to false and it didn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, `GetConnectionString` is just an [extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/ConfigurationExtensions.cs#L19-L22) that simply do the following:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(this IConfiguration configuration, string name)
{
    return configuration?.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")?[name];
}
```

If during debugging you check `Data` in `configuration.Providers` for
you will find the following keys/values among others:

```
key: "connectionStrings:add:MyConn:name" | value: "MyConn"
key: "connectionStrings:add:MyConn:connectionString" | value: "....."
```

That's actually why you got a `null` value.

---

So with the current XML structure, you can simply do:

```
var connString = configuration.GetValue<string>("connectionStrings:add:MyConn:connectionString", string.Empty);
```

Or modify your XML to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <MyConn>conn_string_here</MyConn>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and use

```
var conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConn");
// conn value will be "conn_string_here"
```

Comment: I've used the method of modifying the XML file. The only small issue is that Visual Studio warns that  the XML element `connectionStrings` has invalid child element of `MyConn`.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core's Configuration does not treat .config files any different than XML files. That is, you can't add the connection string "the old way", by having an `add` tag, as this would create quite weird config keys:

[image: Configuration provider internals]

If you want to use XML files, the correct way of specifying the connection string would be:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <MyConn>....</MyConn>
</connectionStrings>
```