# AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'ContextClass' only declares a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

## Detail

I am trying to create asp.net core application and use scaffold-dbcontext to generate class. when I run this app it shows me the error. I already follow some answer on stackoverflow with the same issue but mine remains. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947795/adddbcontext-was-called-with-configuration-but-the-context-type-mycontext-onl/45947912?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

## MyContext

```
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }


    public virtual DbSet<Answer> Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=MyContext;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { .... }
}
```

## Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddMvc()
       .AddJsonOptions(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All);

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    }
```

## Error

> AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'MyContext ' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to AddDbContext will never be used. If configuration is passed to AddDbContext, then 'MyContext ' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: Did you modified the scaffolded `MyContext` class? Have you already cleaned up and rebuilt the whole solution? Why do you have two `AddMvc()` calls in your `Startup.cs`?

Comment: this is a partial class .. are you using MyContext class in any other file?

Comment: I already clean the solution

Comment: No I am not using MyContext in any other file

Comment: How did you solve this problem in the end ?

Comment: @Nashmár I accidentally create to classes of same name db context in same solution but different project. then I delete it the second one.

Answer (score 1):

in appsetting.json file
declare your connection string with name "DefaultConnection"

```
"Data": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=DBname; Integrated Security=True"
}
```

Comment: The answer seems in one of the comments, 2 classes with the same name...